# Append multiple values from other tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, append, concatenation

I have a database with 2 tables, in which I must append data from table 1 to the description of table 2. Table 1 has multiple columns:

- Rent
- Rent_per
- Rent_val

I need to update 1 column, lets call it description, from table 2, with the values of table 1, and specifically these 3 columns.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>name</td>
<td>rent</td>
<td>rent_per</td>
<td>rent_val</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>prod1</td>
<td>yes</td>
<td>day</td>
<td>15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>prod2</td>
<td>no</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>prod3<td>
<td>yes</td>
<td>week</td>
<td>45</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I must append this data to the description, I thought that could be done with CONCAT, the same way as you echo in PHP the different values:

```
    SELECT table2.description AS old_description,
       CONCAT(table2.description, '\n', '\n', 'For ',table1.Rent_per,' per ',table1.Rent_val, you can rent this piece.') AS new_description
FROM   table2
JOIN   table1 ON table1.name = table2.name AND 
       table1.Rent = 'Ja'
```

DESIRED RESULT:

Instead of the old description `...`

I want `... <br /> For 15 euro per day u can rent this piece.`

The problem is this doesn't work like that. I can't do this. I've searched quite a bit on the internet, and I know this has to be done with CONCAT, only I need to do a step between CONCAT and making these new values..

I use the Rent column to only take the entry's which can be rented (it's yes or no), the Rent_per which says if you can rent it for 1 day, week, or month, and the Rent_val is the price it costs.

Comment: Edit your question and include (1) sample data; (2) desired results; and (3) the full query your are attempting.

Comment: I've added the full query, I dont think sample data is needed, as well as the desired result, but correct me if im wrong

Comment: @HuubS all three are needed

Comment: Added all three... I can also do this with multiple queries, or make a new column and add the new description there, but I think this can be done with one query..